# Xamarin.iOS. Appodeal. NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[APDImage imageUrl]

Tags: objective-c, exception, xamarin.ios, appodeal

Xamarin.iOS. Appodeal. Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[APDImage imageUrl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x280002420

[image]

```
class NativeAdDelegate : APDNativeAdLoaderDelegate
{
    NativeAdView _nativeAdView;

    public NativeAdDelegate(NativeAdView nativeAdView) =>
        _nativeAdView = nativeAdView;

    public override void NativeAdLoader(APDNativeAdLoader loader, NSError error) =>
        Console.WriteLine("APDNativeAd DidFailToLoadWithError");

    public override void NativeAdLoader(APDNativeAdLoader loader, NSArray nativeAds) =>
        _nativeAdView.DidLoad(nativeAds.GetItem<APDNativeAd>(0));
}
```

In

> nativeAds.GetItem(0)

I have title and descriptionText, but I haven't images. I get exception in nativeAds.GetItem(0).IconImage.ImageUrl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

APDImage * mainImage - Bitmap of an image. An ad object contains both icon and image. It’s mandatory to use at least one of these elements.

> Deprecated method.

For more details you can refer [here](https://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=20&full=1&platform=4).

```
public override void NativeAdLoader(APDNativeAdLoader loader, NSArray nativeAds)
{
    _nativeAdView.DidLoad(nativeAds.GetItem<APDNativeAd>(0));
}

public void DidLoad(APDNativeAd nativeAd)
{
     this.nativeAd = nativeAd;
     UIView view = new UIView();
     view.Frame = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(10, 30, 200, 200);
     view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(96, 36, 36);
     View.AddSubview(view);
     this.nativeAd.AttachToView(view, UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController);
     this.myMediaView.SetNativeAd(this.nativeAd, this);
     View.AddSubview(this.myMediaView); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The images is required.Otherwise the property `ImageUrl` will return a null value ,which will cause the issue.

```
public override void DidLoadNativeAds(APDNativeAdLoader loader, APDNativeAd[] nativeAds)
  {
      _nativeAdView.DidLoad(nativeAds[0]);
  }
```

For more details you can refer [here](https://github.com/appodeal/appodeal-xamarin-ios).

Comment: I get information [here](https://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=22&full=1&platform=4) .

`public override void NativeAdLoader(APDNativeAdLoader loader, APDNativeAd nativeAd)
  {
   _controller.MyDelegateServiceDidLoad(nativeAd);
  }`